# How can I implement Matthews Correlation Coefficient in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to implement Matthews Correlation Coefficient as metric for fitting models in a Keras deep neural network. I can do it in binary classification problems, but I can't implement it in a way to works with multi class classification problems.

I checked the source for scikit-learn MCC which works with binary and multiclass problems. I tried to adapt it for using Keras backend but I couldn't work it out.

It is be very important to have as I need that to compare with binary classification problems that are evaluated using MCC.

Here is the code for the binary implemantion:

```
def matthews_correlation(y_true, y_pred):
  y_pred_pos = K.round(K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1))
  y_pred_neg = 1 - y_pred_pos
  y_pos = K.round(K.clip(y_true, 0, 1))
  y_neg = 1 - y_pos
  tp = K.sum(y_pos * y_pred_pos)
  tn = K.sum(y_neg * y_pred_neg)
  fp = K.sum(y_neg * y_pred_pos)
  fn = K.sum(y_pos * y_pred_neg)
  numerator = (tp * tn - fp * fn)
  denominator = K.sqrt((tp + fp) * (tp + fn) * (tn + fp) * (tn + fn))
  return numerator / (denominator + K.epsilon())
```

The code I'm trying to adapt from sklearn is following:

```
def matthews_correlation_v2(y_true,y_pred):
  lb = LabelEncoder()
  lb.fit(K.concatenate([y_true, y_pred]))
  y_true = lb.transform(y_true)
  y_pred = lb.transform(y_pred)

  C = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=sample_weight)
  t_sum = C.sum(axis=1, dtype=np.float64)
  p_sum = C.sum(axis=0, dtype=np.float64)
  n_correct = np.trace(C, dtype=np.float64)
  n_samples = p_sum.sum()
  cov_ytyp = n_correct * n_samples - np.dot(t_sum, p_sum)
  cov_ypyp = n_samples ** 2 - np.dot(p_sum, p_sum)
  cov_ytyt = n_samples ** 2 - np.dot(t_sum, t_sum)
  mcc = cov_ytyp / np.sqrt(cov_ytyt * cov_ypyp)
  return mcc
```

Comment: What's the keras implementation that you have so far?